# How can I deep copy an object which has a wrapped function?

Tags: python, inheritance, copy, wrapper

So I was having this problem I didn't understand about a variable showing in different ways depending on the function I used in the container having it as an attribute. I managed to boil it down to the following code:

```py
import copy
from functools import wraps


def do_wrapping(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args):
        return func(*args)
    return wrapper


class Container:
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var
        self.show = self._show_method

    @property
    def show(self):
        return self._show

    @show.setter
    def show(self, shower):
        self._show = do_wrapping(shower)

    def _show_method(self):
        print(self.var)

first_container = Container(1)
second_container = copy.deepcopy(first_container)
second_container.var = 0
second_container.show()
second_container._show_method()
```

I would like both the methods to print out `0`, but the first prints `1`.
This problem is solved using this line `second_container.show = second_container._show_method`, but I would like to avoid it as it seems quite hacky.

In my real case, the wrapping is a bit more complicated so I cannot get rid of it. If you remove the wrapping, it works as expected. I assume when wrapped, the function is kind of "set in stone" but I wouldn't know how to explain it.

So my question is 2 folds:
- why doesn't this code work as expected (2 outputs are `0`) ?
- how should I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're creating `second_container` with `deepcopy`, its `__init__` method is never called, so its `_show` attribute is copied from `first_container`'s. Since `first_container._show` is a function wrapping `first_container._show_method`, that's what you get when you call `second_container.show()`

With your simple example, you could just call `second_container.__init__(0)` instead of `second_container.var = 0`. It's a bit unusual, but it might work in your actual code.

If you can't call the copied object's `__init__` method, I think my preferred approach would be to make the function wrapping happen when the `show` getter is called, rather than at `__init__` time:

```py
class ContainerParent(object):
    @property
    def show(self):
        return do_wrapping(self._show)

    @show.setter
    def show(self, shower):
        self._show = shower
```

If that's not feasible, well, there are lots of other possibilities - for example, you could make `var` a property and move the `self.show = self._show_method` line into its setter - but it's hard to say what would be best without knowing more about your actual code.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of a property and a setter it should work nicely. However, I don't understand why the wrapping mechanism causes such a problem from your question.

Comment: The first paragraph of my answer is the key one. When you `deepcopy` your first object, its `_show` attribute is already the wrapped version of its `_show_method`. That attribute is copied, so the second object's `_show` attribute is _the same function_. Setting `var` doesn't change that (but calling `__init__` would, because it calls the setter again.) I hope that helps. If not I'd recommend adding some print statements for debugging and playing around with your example in the interpreter.

Comment: So I tried changing the value of `var` in the `first_container` to `2` and then the `show` of the `second_container` printed `2`. So I guess it's because when you wrap, you wrap a function that's arbitrary, not necessarily linked to the object. Therefore deepcopying won't preserve the link you originally intended to have. It makes sense, thanks.